# Remove extra Zeros in percentage in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a query to get % from two summed columns. It gives me correct % but the zeros are not going off, even if I use round function. The result like this 95.40000
how I can remove the extra zeros.

```
Select (Round((COUNT(Id * 100) / Total,1)) AS Percentage
```

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? Usually it's the responsibility of the client that displays the result to format the data to the desired number of decimals

Answer (score 0):

Use CAST()

Exemple:

```
Select ( (CAST(NUMBER/100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)))) AS Percentage 
from MyTable
```

In your case:

```
Select CAST((Round((COUNT(Id * 100) / Total,1)) as AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS Percentage
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

As bAN, use cast(), but cast as float :

```
Select cast((Round((COUNT(Id * 100) / Total,1)) as float) AS Percentage
```

Comment: why float for percentage? Thanks for improving my answer

Comment: The default action is to get rid of the zero's plus float is a little smaller to store than decimal(10,2). You should predominantly be working with floats when doing anything mathematical in a database